# Php unzip not working

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am posting my file using jQuery and https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js and trying to unzip using the following php:

```
    if($_FILES["folder"]["name"]) {
        $filename = $_FILES["folder"]["name"];
        $source = $_FILES["folder"]["tmp_name"];
        $type = $_FILES["folder"]["type"];

        $zip = new ZipArchive;     
        $res = $zip->open($source);
        if ($res === TRUE) {
             $zip->extractTo('themes');
             $zip->close();
             echo 'Unzip was successful';
        } else {
             echo 'Unzip was not successful';
        }

    } else {
        echo "NOT SET";            
    }
```

Firebug Console returns "Unzip was successful" but there is not folder created in the themes folder. Can anyone suggest why this does not create the folder?

Comment: extractTo also returns boolean value, try to check it

Comment: Is themes an existing folder where your script locates?

Comment: your script seems fine maybe your destination path(themes/) is not match?

Comment: @makriria It is a existing folder. My php file is in the same directory as my themes folder. I have also played allot with the path. If the path is incorrect would it still return "Unzip was successful" ?

Comment: ZipArchive::open returns an error code when it fails, what does it return? See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   if ($res === TRUE) {
         $res = $zip->extractTo('themes');
         if ($res === TRUE) {
              echo 'Unzip was successful';
         }
    } 
    $zip->close();
    if ( $res === false ) {
         echo 'Unzip was not successful';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the web user (www-data on Apache) has permissions to write to the destination directory.